# Unable to send a Base 64 image to Woocommerce /product API with JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am actually trying to make a 3D product configurator with verge 3D and have to create new WooCommerce products for every specific product configuration.

Everything seem to work fine and I managed to generate an image capture stored in a variable as base 64 jpeg

I now want to post this variable to /wp-json/wc/v2/products/ with the rest of my product creation query but the API return "Invalid URL Provided."

I fear that the WooCommerce Product REST API can't handle base64 images as img -> src:
however some people seem to have managed to pass similar requests.

I included below my JSON code, maybe there is a problem with the formatting...

```
{
"name": "Config Plexi",
"type": "simple",
"regular_price": "21.99",
"dimensions": {
    "length": "300",
    "width": "300"
},
"description": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique",
"images": [
{   "src":"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
    }
]
```

}

If the functionality mentioned above is not available, I think I will have to use an external PHP file as my configurator code is entirely written in JS

I found the code below but I now need a function to send my base 64 image to the PHP function and retrieve the generated URL to include it in my JSON request

```
/**
 * Save the image on the server.
 */
function save_image( $base64_img, $title ) {

    // Upload dir.
    $upload_dir  = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $img             = str_replace( 'data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $base64_img );
    $img             = str_replace( ' ', '+', $img );
    $decoded         = base64_decode( $img );
    $filename        = $title . '.jpeg';
    $file_type       = 'image/jpeg';
    $hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;

    // Save the image in the uploads directory.
    $upload_file = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded );

    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $file_type,
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $hashed_filename ) ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'guid'           => $upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $hashed_filename )
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $hashed_filename );
}
```

I am actually struggling to link JS and PHP

```
//This function is called when add to cart or purchase button are pressed 
function apicrpr(state) {
//This read form values to use is later in the API request

  var longueur = document.getElementById("longueure").value,
    largeur = document.getElementById("largeure").value,
    épaisseur = document.getElementById("épaisseur").value,
    quantité = document.getElementById("quantité").value,
    matériaux = document.getElementById("matériaux").value,
    mac = document.getElementById("matériaux"),
    macval = mac.options[mac.selectedIndex].text,
    final = document.getElementById("prxxx").innerHTML,
    finalp = parseFloat(final.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g));

//Return my base 64 image as displayed in the JSON above 
    var canvas = takeshot();

//Create request 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }

    else{
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
//The actual url of the PHP code written above 
     var PageToSendTo = "https://websiteadress.com/wp-includes/uploadimg.php?";
     var MyVariable = canvas;
     var VariablePlaceholder = "base64_img=";
     var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + MyVariable + "&title=Product_Image";
//I would like my PHP code to execute an get the url of my image back but I'm kinda lost here 
     xmlhttp.open("POST", UrlToSend, false);
     xmlhttp.send();
```

I hope I had been clear enough
Thank you so much in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can make communication between js & php using cookies.using expiry date of cookies you can determine when data will be vanished